# Curve fitting in R. L-shaped?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, ggplot2

I have measurements for my dependent and independent variable across 4 different experimental sites

```
> df
    SITE     depend  independ
1      b  168.00000  6.441205
2      b  175.00000  6.939212
3      b  231.00000  6.370073
4      b  185.00000  6.816244
5      b   56.00000  4.839825
6      b  295.00000  7.032590
7      b  277.00000  7.473761
8      b  126.00000  5.791581
9      b  391.00000  8.209857
10     b  200.00000  5.607706
11     b  701.00000  9.457697
12     b  371.00000  7.509605
13     b   96.00000  5.938662
14     b  259.00000  7.868018
15     b  456.00000  8.397162
16     b 1382.00000 12.085675
17     b  323.00000  7.136464
18     b   96.00000  5.624912
19     b  346.00000  7.483332
20     b  799.00000  9.395876
21     b 1060.00000 10.792450
22     b  544.00000  7.750952
23     b  173.00000  6.157235
24     b  196.00000  6.967660
25     b  366.00000  6.851160
26     b  356.00000  7.438638
27     b  277.00000  7.017364
28     b   74.00000  5.881512
29     b  119.00000  6.370771
30     b  254.00000  6.694148
31     b  490.00000  7.915398
32     b  254.00000  6.936110
33     b  182.00000  6.252873
34     b   89.00000  6.130857
35     b  357.00000  7.154955
36     b  499.00000  6.590502
37     b  184.00000  6.546551
38     b   41.00000  5.147197
39     b   40.00000  5.668956
40     b  208.00000  5.465280
41     b  283.00000  4.424971
42     b  224.00000  4.801846
43     b   54.00000  4.065652
44     b   52.00000  3.856986
45     b  199.00000  4.183085
46     b  213.00000  4.173327
47     b  260.00000  4.882182
48     b  111.00000  4.198152
49     b   33.00000  3.884470
50     b  268.00000  5.079467
51     b  110.00000  3.325862
52     b  104.00000  4.051622
53     b  154.00000  4.247760
54     b   25.00000  3.762566
55     b  136.00000  3.752807
56     c  241.56199 19.615185
57     c  350.59535 24.304213
58     c  214.17054 24.748324
59     c  182.54479 17.528364
60     c  236.96800 21.447088
61     c  271.30102 22.423033
62     c  185.08586 15.571394
63     c  160.93738 22.328360
64     c  197.55959 22.180291
65     c  103.83524 17.468660
66     c  142.56036 23.997938
67     c   81.42678 19.299329
68     c   84.22605 17.881147
69     c  115.94955 24.141446
70     c  133.42529 23.062898
71     c  102.53631 20.277638
72     c   84.36548 30.151952
73     c   84.47937 21.096182
74     c  236.27805 30.099155
75     c  349.90029 35.396363
76     c  444.88595 30.248578
77     c  296.82142 24.704304
78     c  510.57317 39.110463
79     c  486.37477 30.426705
80     c  236.41881 29.255599
81     c  355.17601 42.052473
82     c  607.77522 38.420525
83     c  232.72935 27.145563
84     c  195.29648 38.246792
85     c  268.11658 28.665716
86     c  193.83150 25.691579
87     c  190.96397 37.430981
88     c  330.81237 30.617868
89     c  227.35598 28.136638
90     c  217.53775 45.928556
91     c  326.69894 35.236348
92     a   84.82300  7.890941
93     a   65.92033  9.602303
94     a  112.02938 12.577319
95     a  102.07078  9.691760
96     a   37.54533  9.783016
97     a   92.96748  8.648471
98     a   84.82300  6.534176
99     a   65.92033  8.798907
100    a  112.02938 10.611139
101    a  102.07078  8.045100
102    a   37.54533  8.198559
103    a   92.96748  7.025727
104    a  277.99407  8.703563
105    a  274.67549 10.283912
106    a  209.35391 11.160171
107    a  374.62773 10.802339
108    a  189.12355  9.353084
109    a  169.75574  8.936873
110    a  114.04921  8.538088
111    a  130.17711 10.294958
112    a  157.86700 13.335407
113    a  132.83674  9.725718
114    a  160.14794  9.982123
115    a   88.51967  8.477415
116    a   55.69747  7.447332
117    a   44.33433  8.652240
118    a   64.56533 11.329548
119    a  186.16691  8.889405
120    a  116.22274  9.639093
121    a   54.38541  7.864175
122    a   32.72340  4.700851
123    a   72.46003  6.249158
124    a   91.10478  9.106591
125    a   33.92287  5.025721
126    a   59.61350  6.111414
127    a   63.97190  4.678834
128    a  315.13820  9.481181
129    a  321.52545  9.871237
130    a  154.74091 11.628064
131    a  313.95592 11.068721
132    a  127.80241  8.436874
133    a  166.27027  8.384337
134    a   76.69727  8.832208
135    a  126.71580 11.029189
136    a   91.79080 14.895407
137    a  151.48970 12.856855
138    a  195.59343 11.122149
139    a   74.91341  9.317945
140    a  295.98038  8.836945
141    a  166.43070 10.310140
142    a  154.86179 13.008521
143    a   61.32212  8.405404
144    a  187.58412  9.435029
145    a   72.45953  6.694838
146    d   42.26709        NA
147    d   67.27785        NA
148    d   48.16153        NA
149    d   59.61941        NA
150    d   46.86858        NA
151    d   67.23354        NA
152    d   37.77909        NA
153    d   67.38458        NA
154    d   33.75093        NA
155    d   53.47952        NA
156    d   44.86217        NA
157    d   61.34711        NA
158    d   47.07810  3.584784
159    d   76.03665  7.017740
160    d   52.12276  3.198352
161    d   67.70569  5.703212
162    d   51.54876  3.691451
163    d   80.90385  7.080591
164    d   42.34507  4.628310
165    d   85.94787 10.013365
166    d   39.04737  4.064594
167    d   60.19088  5.686637
168    d   49.23514  4.251856
169    d   71.77600  6.751174
170    d   55.90435  5.171524
171    d   91.84596 10.160686
172    d   63.31703  5.462032
173    d   82.71376  8.437648
174    d   61.36583  5.190954
175    d   99.50947  9.114059
176    d   49.37328  6.218972
177    d   99.14676  9.550849
178    d   44.57117  4.741055
179    d   71.89609  7.256575
180    d   56.47511  5.391315
181    d   87.06737  8.078044
182    d   65.56232  6.499106
183    d  104.74657 10.127041
184    d   72.55353  6.557808
185    d   80.90207  7.438215
186    d  102.16351  6.449129
187    d   90.54294  9.340280
188    d   54.45511  7.369644
189    d  136.64572  8.907776
190    d   51.85764  6.122434
191    d   98.67447  6.588543
192    d   67.20106  6.847232
193    d  120.43387  9.726845
```

[image]

The hypothesis was that the dependent variable would decrease as the independent variable increases, but after a first look it seems that the hypothesis might be wrong.

I must admit my inexperience, so please, help me decide which type of trendline I could add to my points. Is it exponential? Looks slightly like an L-shaped. Or just scattered with no trend at all?

I have tried to fit a gam model, but the curve does not fit the upper left points.

```
ggplot(df,aes(independ,depend)) + geom_point(aes(col=SITE)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), size = 1,col="red",se=F)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a _Gamma_ or _Weibull_ distributions? It might be a _mixture distribution_ as well.

Comment: No single function will fit these data satisfactorily--don't waste your time looking for one.  There is a clear difference between the trend at site $b$ and all other sites. Your hypothesis is just too simple to be useful. You might want to explore these data to develop a more suitable hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. For the moment I think I will discuss this with my colleges and see what they suggest

Comment: A single curve across sites doesn't make sense here. You have heteroskedasticity, curvature, and different relationships by site. It's possible to find quite reasonable models, but you need to say more about what the point of your analysis is. [Is this for some class or is it your own data?]

Comment: This is my data, that I am analysing with the idea to publish the conclusions. The dependent variable is the percentage of plant productivity allocated to roots, and the independent variable is nitrogen availability in the soil. When N availability is low, root growth should be very large in order to increase soil exploration and increase plant N availability. When N availability is high, plants should reduce the percentage of allocation to roots because there is no point in increasing N availability further.